# Why is the size of structure pointer **s when derefenced to '*s' and further to 's' is 8 in the below code in C? . Can anybody please explain it

Tags: c++, c, pointers, structure, sizeof

> Structure

```
     struct student
     {
              int rollno;
              char name[10];
              float marks;
     };
```

> main Function

```
     void main()
     {
              struct student **s;
              int n;
```

> Total size of memory to be dynamically allocated

```
              printf("Enter total number of students:\n");
              scanf("%d",&n);

              printf("Size of **s: %ld\n", sizeof(**s));
```

> Why the size of *s and s is 8 here ?

```
              printf("Size of *s: %ld\n", sizeof(*s));

              printf("Size of s: %ld\n", sizeof(s));

              s = (struct student **)malloc(sizeof(struct student *)* n);
```

> Allocating memory dynamically to array of pointers

```
              for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                   s[i]=malloc(sizeof(struct student));
```

> User defined data

```
              for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
              {
                   printf("Enter the roll no:\n");
                   scanf("%d",&s[i]->rollno);

                   printf("Enter name:\n");
                   scanf("%s",s[i]->name);

                   printf("Enter marks:\n");
                   scanf("%f",&s[i]->marks);
              }

              printf("Size of **s:%ld\n",sizeof(**s));
              for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                    printf("%d %s %f\n", s[i]->rollno, s[i]->name, s[i]->marks);

              free(s);
     }
```

Comment: Both of the `sizeof()` expressions have a pointer type as an argument. What would you expect them to be?

Comment: Note that the most appropriate conversion specifier for `size_t` (the result type from `sizeof`) is `%zu`.

Comment: When I tried finding out the size of pointer then I found that it is 4 bytes. I know the pointer size is machine dependent, irrespective of any pointer type. but when tried to find the size of pointer assigned to the structure it gave as 8 bytes, so my concern is why is there two different sizes for these pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer types are as big as they need to be to represent an address on the host system.  On x86-64 platforms, all pointer types tend to be 64 bits, or 8 8-bit bytes, wide.  The *expressions* `s` and `*s` both have pointer type (`struct student **` and `struct student *`, respectively), so on your platform they’re both 8 bytes wide.

The sizes of pointer types will be different on different platforms, and different pointer types on the same platform may have different sizes.  The only requirements are:

- `char *` and `void *` have the same size and alignment;
- Pointers to qualified types have the same size and alignment as their unqualified equivalents (e.g., `sizeof (const int *) == sizeof (int *)`)
- All `struct` pointer types have the same size and alignment;
- All `union` pointer types have the same size and alignment.

Comment: When I tried finding out the size of pointer then I found that it is 4 bytes. I know the pointer size is machine dependent, irrespective of any pointer type. but when tried to find the size of pointer assigned to the structure it gave as 8 bytes.

Comment: @SavyTech:  What told you the pointer size was 4 bytes?  Another `sizeof` expression?

Comment: Re “Pointer types are as big as they need to be to represent an address on the host system”: Not actually true. I worked with a C implementation that used 32-bit pointers on a 64-bit-address system.

Comment: @JohnBode: Yes, I got clarified thanks for you detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

> Why the size of *s and s is 8 here ?

Reason :`*s` is a pointer (`struct student*`), `s` is a pointer to a pointer (`struct student**`) .
And the size of a pointer is 8 bytes (64 bit system)